# How can i add validation to otp filed when otp field is empty in flutter

Tags: validation, flutter, textfield, flutter-layout, one-time-password

here I get some problems. how I can I add validation to the plaintext field or any field which is used for OTP enter. if someone has another field for OTP entering please let me know. hope you understand. please help me.

[image]

```
  _onAlertotp(context) {
    Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "OTP expires in: MM:SS (Counter",
        desc:
            "We have Texted and/or Emailed OTP (One Time Pin) to your registered cell phone and/ or email account. Please check and enter OTP below to activate your TUDO account",
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              autovalidate: true,
              child: PinField(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  length: 6,
                  gap: 6.0,
                  onSubmitted: Validators().otpValidate,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
                  inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]),
            )
          ],
        ),
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "Resend OTP",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _onAlertrunningbusiness(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              "Enter Otp",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          )
        ]).show();
  }
```

Comment: there is no validator property for this field

Answer (score 3):

In order to validate an empty string you'll just need to check if it's value equals "" or not.

You can use the getter function `isEmpty()` to check if the String is empty or not.

**Solution Code:**

```
 validator: (String value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return "Please enter phone number";
                        } else if (value.length != 10) {
                          return "Please enter valid Phone number";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
```

Comment: No we don't have validator property in thr pin text field. Sugget something else. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different library: https://pub.dev/packages/otp_text_field. But your library also have '**onChanged**' parameter.

```
static const int _otpLength = 6;
    
OTPTextField(
  length: _otpLength,
  onChanged: (code) {
      _onOtpValidated(code.length == _otpLength);
  },
),

void _onOtpValidated(bool isValid) {
    // make your validation flag true
}
```